# Create Custom Seekbar in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, seekbar

can any one help me to create balow image cutomize seek bar 
i have already go throught 
[SeekBar with custom thumb and segmented text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646898/seekbar-with-custom-thumb-and-segmented-text)
and [SeekBar Thumb position issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887556/seekbar-thumb-position-issue)

but i am not success to create my custome seekbar pls help me

[image: Images is here]

Comment: Can you post your code? What is the problem? Are there errors? Can you post them too and a logcat. Without them we have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: thanx RossC, i want to create seekbar as above , how can i create this? i am not getting any error so which helps you, but i am not getting required output , can you have some sample code or link which helps me than please provide thanx again..

Comment: Ok, I can't really do anything other than link to 'SeekBar' and let you run with that. If you haven't tried anything, what can I do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar

Comment: no problem but i already go throught it. thanx :-)

Comment: Great, glad to hear it! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Library From This Link: [This link](http://code.google.com/p/regie-eclairage-saint-michel/source/browse/trunk/Tablette/VerticalSlidebarExample/?r=20) and put into your project,

Now Create A Seekbar Like This Class:

```
package com.tokaracamara.android.verticalslidevar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
public class DemoSeek extends AbsVerticalSeekBar {
    public interface OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        void onProgressChanged(DemoSeek seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser);

    void onStartTrackingTouch(DemoSeek seekBar);

    void onStopTrackingTouch(DemoSeek seekBar);
}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener mOnSeekBarChangeListener;

private Drawable progressDrawable;
private Rect barBounds, labelTextRect;
private Bitmap labelBackground;
private Point labelPos;
private Paint labelTextPaint, labelBackgroundPaint;

int viewWidth, barHeight, labelOffset;
//    private int thumbX;
float progressPosX;
private String expression;

public DemoSeek(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Log.i("Seekbar", "DemoSeek");
    progressDrawable = getProgressDrawable();

    // labelBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    // R.drawable.thumb_marker);

    labelBackground = drawableToBitmap(mThumb);

    labelTextPaint = new Paint();
    labelTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    labelTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    labelTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    labelTextPaint.setDither(true);
    labelTextPaint.setTextSize(13f);

    labelBackgroundPaint = new Paint();

    barBounds = new Rect();
    labelTextRect = new Rect();

    labelPos = new Point();

}

public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

@Override
void onProgressRefresh(float scale, boolean fromUser) {
    super.onProgressRefresh(scale, fromUser);

    if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
        mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, getProgress(),
                fromUser);
    }
}

public DemoSeek(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    progressDrawable = getProgressDrawable();

    labelBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.thumb_with_arrow);

    labelTextPaint = new Paint();
    labelTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    labelTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    labelTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    labelTextPaint.setDither(true);
    labelTextPaint.setTextSize(15f);

    labelBackgroundPaint = new Paint();

    barBounds = new Rect();
    labelTextRect = new Rect();

    labelPos = new Point();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    // Log.i("Seekbar", "onMeasure");
    if (labelBackground != null) {

        viewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        barHeight = getMeasuredHeight() - getPaddingTop()
                - getPaddingBottom();
        setMeasuredDimension(viewWidth + labelBackground.getWidth(),
                barHeight + labelBackground.getHeight() / 2);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    if (labelBackground != null) {
        barBounds.left = getPaddingLeft();
        barBounds.top = (int) (labelBackground.getHeight() / 2f);
        barBounds.right = barBounds.left + viewWidth - getPaddingRight()
                - getPaddingLeft();
        barBounds.bottom = barBounds.top + barHeight - getPaddingBottom()
                - getPaddingTop();

        progressPosX = barBounds.top
                + ((float) this.getProgress() / (float) this.getMax())
                * barBounds.height() + getTopPaddingOffset();

        labelPos.y = getBottom() - (int) progressPosX - labelOffset
                + (int) (getProgress() * 0.1f);
        labelPos.x = getPaddingLeft();

        progressDrawable = getProgressDrawable();

        progressDrawable.setBounds(barBounds.left, barBounds.top,
                barBounds.right, getBottom());

        progressDrawable.draw(canvas);

        String pro = getProgress() * multiplier + "";
        if (expression != null) {
            pro = pro.concat(expression);
        }
        labelTextPaint.getTextBounds(pro, 0, pro.length(), labelTextRect);

        canvas.drawBitmap(labelBackground, labelPos.x, labelPos.y,
                labelBackgroundPaint);

        canvas.drawText(pro, labelPos.x + labelBackground.getWidth() / 2
                - labelTextRect.width() / 2 + 15, labelPos.y
                + labelBackground.getHeight() / 2 + labelTextRect.height()
                / 2 - 5, labelTextPaint);

    }
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    invalidate();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

}

public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
        com.tokaracamara.android.verticalslidevar.DemoSeek.OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener) {
    mOnSeekBarChangeListener = (OnSeekBarChangeListener) onSeekBarChangeListener;
}

@Override
void onStartTrackingTouch() {
    if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
        mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
    }
}

@Override
void onStopTrackingTouch() {
    if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
        mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
    }
}


private int multiplier = 1;

public void setMultiplier(int multiplier) {
    this.multiplier = multiplier;
}

public int getMultiplier() {
    return multiplier;
}

public void setExpression(String expression) {
    this.expression = expression.trim();
}

public String getExpression() {
    return expression;
}
```

}

Create Xml Like This:

```
<com.tokaracamara.android.verticalslidevar.DemoSeek
            android:id="@+id/v_four_university"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/vs_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:progress="50"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_vertical"
            android:saveEnabled="false"
            android:thumb="@drawable/your thumb" />
```

Comment: This is working code. by mistake I down voted.when I up vote this says "You last voted on this answer 16 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.". @Kishan can you edit the answer. Thanks