# How to create customized seek bar in android?

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

I want the customized seekbar like following one. It contains a thumb with TextView. 
[image]

Comment: Use this:
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574271/create-custom-seekbar-in-android) to create your own customized seekbar. because i have spent long time for creating this.